# Azure: Server configured on the same vnet couldnt talk with each other

Tags: azure

I have 2 canonical Ubuntu 16.04 VMS configured in the same vnet located in the same region. When I ping with the public ip on the other server the packets are not transmitted.

Why is these 2 VMS are not able to talk with each other? Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I ping with the public ip on the other server the packets are not
>   transmitted.

It is a by design behavior, Azure does not support use `ping`.

In Azure, 2 VMs in the same Vnet, VM can ping another VM with `private IP address`.

Also you can use [Psping](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping) to test the connection.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: There is no way for the azure vm to reach another azure vm with their public ip?

Comment: @Minisha Just not work for `ping`, you can use telnet to test it.